# Sending ctrl-r to bash in a python subprocess

Tags: python

When pressing `ctrl-r` in bash, I can see `(reverse-i-search)` prompt.

In python, I can open a bash process like this

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['bash'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Now can I send `ctrl-r` information to this process and read the `(reverse-i-search)` prompt in python?

I'm doing to learn `pty`, and I'm just wondering if it's possible to code a terminal emulator without using `pty`.

Comment: In theory you should be able to run `showkey --scancodes` and write the exact same output to your subprocess. For whatever reason I can't get input and output to work on my virtual machine but it should be as simple as `p.stdin.write(b'^R)` if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: you need this because you need to send it inside a VM?

Comment: @iugene I'm just curious if this could be done.

Comment: OK. I am doing this but from a host inside a virtual machine. On a local computer I didn't try it yet.

Comment: @iugene If it's working in a VM write it up as an answer I reckon it's correct.

Comment: You may not truly want implementing terminal emulator without using pty. Lot of fuctionality is provided via that interface that otherwise is not easy to be emulated, e.g. signalling (like keyboard interrupt.) And many programs behave differently when connected to a terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Sending the *ctrl-r* character code to the bash process is enough for a start.

However, if bash determines it is not connected to a terminal, it will use *non-interactive* mode. In that mode line-editing is disabled. So, bash will not react on *ctrl-r*. You need to start bash as `bash -i` to get interactive mode.

(And in the rare case that you are using differnt encodings with sender and bash process, ensure you are using the propper char-code for *ctrl-r*.)

So given your example you would just need to use:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-i'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE);
```

to get bash started in interactive mode (having line-editing enabled). Then (assuming ASCII-compatible encoding) you may use (as you already assumed):

```
p.stdin.write('\022');
```

to start search functionality. (Of course, also assuming `p.stdin` denoting stdin of the bash subprocess.)